# Can you ask questions that are very specific to a certain open source project?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I'm customizing [fedena](https://github.com/projectfedena/fedena), which isn't a very popular open source project (their forum is pretty much dead).

So I got a question that although technical, it also requires a good amount of information of the ins and outs of fedena itself. I already [asked it](http://www.projectfedena.org/forum/4-project-fedena-souce-code-related/topics/941-how-to-identify-an-academic-school-year-in-fedena) on the fedena forum (chances of me getting a good answer anytime soon are pretty slim).

I was wondering if it's a kind of question that I can ask on stack over flow without people throwing eggs at me and down voting me.

Comment: SO has a [few fedena questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fedena), I don't see why you shouldn't try asking your own. Can't promise people won't throw eggs at you, however I can promise that if they do, the eggs will land on their screens and not on your face ;)

Comment: This is really an old question , If you are still developing plugins for fedena , make sure that you use [fedena] tag in SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is programming/scripting question, and it fits to SO guidelines (you describe problem precisely, and write what you have tried/what is your research status), it's no problem to ask it on SO, and no reason for downvote.

However, if you get an answer, it's another thing. It's hard to get answer in niche tags because of limited number of experts. But lack of experts is not a reason to be donwvoted or closed.

If your question is more installation/configuration one, it could be better off on SuperUser or ServerFault.